# Fetch certain field using BigCommerce API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Is there a way to fetch a certain field only of a resource using the BigCommerce API? for example fetching the id field only of all products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can just return a filtered list of fields on a get request. If you are using the Ruby gem,

```
orders = api.get_orders
order_id = orders.collect{|o| o["id"]}
```

You can find the gem here - https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby/

Hope this helps!